# embedding python into c++ library

Tags: python, c++

I want to embed python into an shared library.
I use [elmer](http://elmer.sourceforge.net/) to create the c code from a python script. This code I compile into a static library. I used `python2.7-config --cflags --ldflags` to get the [compiler and linker flags for my system](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems).

Now when I want to test this static library with a test application I get many `undefined reference to` errors (for every `Py`- and `el`-function). These errors are located in the (from elmer) generated c file.

I know there is an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue4434) with embedding python. I got this to work in the past one time (without linking my test application to python or elmer) but I do not know how... (yeah, it is better to document something like this^^ )

Comment: Static libraries are not linked. You need to supply Python linker flags when you link your application, as this is the only place the linker is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to n.m. I got the answer:

I learned that while building a static lib the linker is not invoked.
So moving the cflags and ldflags to the next shared lib/application solved the problem.